# Regex difference in sequences

Tags: java, regex

I am not clear on the difference between:
`(...)`
and
`(?:...)`

It seems to me that they both produce the same output but only the first expression can be used for backreferencing.

Am I correct? And if this is indeed their only difference why would we use the second option?
Is it for performance?

Answer (score 2):

That is correct. `(?:...)` is actually **non-capturing** group and it cannot be used for back reference. Reasons why **non-capturing** group is used because there are many instances when you want to group certain segments of your regex together but actually don't want to capture them. DO:

- Use `(...)` when you want group your regex segments and **want** to capture the group
- Use `(?:...)` when you want group your regex segments and **don't want** to capture the group

Answer (score 2):

Back references have a surprisingly high performance impact.   A regex with no back references  can be implemented as a DFA which is O(string_length) to execute.  With back references it has to be a NFA which has a worst case exponential execution time (best case can be fairly fast though).

http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html  and https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/75606/advantages-disadvantages-of-nfa-over-dfa-and-vice-versa  have some more details.

Answer (score 1):

That is correct - performance is the main reason. Also when you're doing things like nesting groups; you might want to have "nice" capture groups for later usage, but also need grouping for things like `|` operators. Similarly, if you are editing a regex that already has capture groups, and you want to add more grouping but don't want to affect the existing capture groups, you could similarly use a non-capturing group.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's the only difference. Performance and readability (ie making your intention clear) and possibly not wasting back references (you only have 9) would be reasons to use the second syntax.